# Adding UV to object

Tags: uv, edit-mode

I am new to blender. I downloaded a blender file and there's the object that I downloaded but it's in gray color. I look at the UV editing and I can see that there are already preset colors, I just don't know how to add it to the object. Can someone please help me with this? Thank you for helping!

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: can you post some pics of what you've got at the moment, such as node setup, the uv settings, etc?

Comment: Sure thing! Thank you for asking

Comment: Are you in render mode?

Comment: I wasn't! Thanks for the help!